# Search and replace lines in a file in python

Tags: python, file

I have a file that was autogenerated. I need to modify/edit the file when the bit-wise operator `|` is found in an if statement for example:

```
  if ((x ==1) | (y==1))
```

Needs to be changed too:

```
   if ((x ==1) || (y==1))
```

So, the bitwise operator needs to be changed to a logical operator, **only** in a conditional statement.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
with open('filename','r') as f:
    file_data = f.readlines()
file_data_str = ''.join(file_data)

for line in file_data:
    if line.lstrip().startswith('if') and ('|' in line):
           
            file_data_str = file_data_str.replace(' | ', ' || ')

with open('filename','w') as f:
    f.write(file_data_str)
```

The current code changes every occurrence of `|` to `||` no matter where `|` is in the file. The desired behavior is to only change `|` to `||` in an if statement.

How do I fix this?

Comment: If the line contains a `|`, you then replace every singe occurrence at once, not just the line.

Comment: @Peter I only need to change the `|` to a `||`  when it's in an if statement. Not every occurrence of `|`. There are lines where `|` occurs and should remain `|` because it's not in an if statement.

Comment: I get it wasn't super clear, but I'm telling you what you are doing, not what you should be doing :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('Text.txt','r') as f:
    file_data = f.readlines()


i=0
while i in range(len(file_data)):
    for line in file_data:
        if file_data[i].lstrip().startswith('if') and ('|' in line):          
            file_data[i]= file_data[i].replace(' | ', ' || ')
    i+=1
file_data_str = ''.join(file_data)

with open('Text.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(file_data_str)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('filename','r') as f:
    file_data = f.readlines()
file_data_str = ''.join(file_data)

for line in file_data:
    if line.lstrip().startswith('if') and ('|' in line):
            #the problem is here: with this statement you change all occurrences
            file_data_str = file_data_str.replace(' | ', ' || ')

with open('filename','w') as f:
    f.write(file_data_str)
```

I would resolve with this:

```
with open('filename','r') as f:
    file_data = f.readlines()

for ii in range(len(file_data)):
    if file_data[ii].lstrip().startswith('if') and ('|' in line):
           
            file_data[ii]= file_data[ii].replace(' | ', ' || ')

file_data_str = ''.join(file_data)

with open('filename','w') as f:
f.write(file_data_str)
```

Comment: The line in your code is not defined in `| in line` . If you mean `i` instead of line then ``ii` is an integer and is not iterable.

Comment: ii is a integer, I usually use ii instead of i and jj for j because they're easier to find in a large file. ii is an index and file_data[ii] is the ii-th line of youre file_data, that is a list of strings btw, and i change any interessed line directly, you can't do that clean with the `for line in file` loop thing

Comment: What I meant you don't define what `line` is.